# Regex in JavaScript replace on } with preceding character

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a problem creating a reg expression.

E.g.: i have the following text "This} is} a} test}"

Now i want to replace every } including any preceded character.

Is this possible in java script with Regex?

The result of this text should be.

"Thi i  tes"

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Use '(\\})' for catching "}"

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
str.replace(/.}/g, '')
```

Comment: thx this solved my problem ;)
I dont know how regex work :D

Comment: @pat: You're welcome. A dot `.` means any character. So this regex will replace every occurrence of one char followed by `}` by nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
var st = "This} is} a} test}";
var rep = st.replace(/.\}/g, "");
console.log(rep);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = "This} is} a} test}";
    var regexp = new RegExp(".}","g");
    test = test.replace(regexp, "");
    alert(test); //"Thi i tes"
</script>
```